# MapPageRoute Interfering with 404 Processing

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404, url-routing

I have a website that makes use of page routing.  I recently added a page to display a friendly error on 404 errors.  Normally, this works.

However, (and this only happens on the server, not on my development machine), for SOME LINKS that look like valid company URL's, but are not, instead of displaying the 404 page, or a 404 error, instead some internal code I haven't been able to find might be catching the error and redirecting to the home page.

The routing for the company page is:
routes.MapPageRoute("Storefront", "Reviews/{DBA}-{ID}", "~/storefront.aspx")

For most store front URL's this works, like this one:
http://207.198.100.250/Reviews/High-Octane-Automotive-207083966

If we make up a fictitious but non-existing link, we see the 404 page:
http://207.198.100.250/Reviews/Low-Octane-Automotive-2070839661

But this link, although it looks like a valid URL, it is not.  But, unlike the made-up one in the example above, this one gets redirected to the home page, not the 404 page:
http://207.198.100.250/Reviews/Uffner-Textiles-206026006

Why?

But more importantly, **HOW CAN I TRACK DOWN the source of the redirect** to the home page?

Thanks!

Comment: Given the fact that none of `Reviews/High-Octane-Automotive-207083966`, `Reviews/Low-Octane-Automotive-2070839661`, or `Reviews/Uffner-Textiles-206026006` matches the route `Reviews/{DBA}-{ID}` (because all of them have more dashes than you have specified in your placeholder), it seems that your issue is due to another route that you haven't posted. Some of those URLs are matching this other route and others are not matching, but unless you post all of the routing configuration, it is impossible for anyone to tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you, NightOwl888.  Your idea is probably correct.  I've examined all the page routing, and this one is the ONLY route for reviews:

Comment: Thank you, NightOwl888.  Your idea is probably correct.  I've examined all the page routing, and this one is the ONLY route for reviews:

routes.MapPageRoute("Storefront", "Reviews/{DBA}-{ID}", "~/mypage.aspx")

And there aren't any other routes that contain "reviews".  Can you think of any reason this routing would not work for some cases?